# C#/.NET MIDI sequencer: Parse MIDI file and generate timed Note-On messages

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, midi

I need to parse a MIDI file and generate note-on messages at the right moments.

I'm currently using a port of http://csharpsynthproject.codeplex.com/
(this is the port [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/130104-UnitySynth-full-Xplatform-midi-synth))

The problem with this port is that the sequencer and the synth are so heavily wrapped up in one another that it is a major headache to try to separate them.

Hence I am looking for an alternative approach.

π

Comment: Please reopen this question, I have reworded it. π

Answer (score 8):

There is [MIDI.NET](https://github.com/obiwanjacobi/midi.net) that has Midi File reading and writing support but no sequencer build in.

There is also the [C# Midi Toolkit](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6228/C-MIDI-Toolkit) that can also read midi files and does come with a sequencer.

full disclosure: I am the author of MIDI.NET